# Three20 : TTTableImageItem and URL containing space and special characters

Tags: three20

I have a this code :

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tt://classObj?title=%@", obl.title];

    TTTableImageItem *cell = [TTTableImageItem 
                               itemWithText:obl.title
                               imageURL:obl.thumbURL
                               URL:url];
```

If my obl.title contains special characters like é à ç ô or a simple space, it's not correctly mapped to my selector :

```
- (id)initWithFailDetails:(NSString *)title query:(NSDictionary*)query
```

Is there any way to pass parameters containing these type of characters? By escaping them of whatever solution it may exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `base64` encoding, *(from memory url escaping won't work)* OR
2. do not use URLs to pass such parameters but use instead `TTURLAction -applyQuery` +

   `- (id)initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query`

Comment: Thank you! It works really well with the - (id)initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query :)

Comment: de rien :) urls with parameters are really needed when you want to cleanly separate view controllers, like to use the `TTNavigator` persistence system. Which is less an less needed with iOS4/multitasking, and a pain to implement. Communicating Objects is so easier!